# Regex error: expression took longer than ms to execute

Tags: c#, css, regex

So this is my regex pattern for extracting CSS from a specific string using C#:

```
(([\s]*\/\*[^\*]+\*\/)?((@media|@keyframes)[^{]+\{[\s]*)?(((\b(html|head|body|a|abbr|area|audio|b|base|blockquote|button|canvas|code|datalist|dialog|div)|em|embed|font|footer|form|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6|header|hr|i|iframe|img|input|label|li|link|main|map|menu|meta|object|ol|optgroup|option|output|p|param|pre|section|select|span|strong|sup|table|textarea|tfoot|th|head|td|title|tr|u|ul|video|\*))\b)?((\.|\#|\[)[^\s,\.\#\|]+)*([:]{1,2}[^\s,]+)*((\s)|(\,)|(\+)|(\~)|(&gt;)|(&telde;))*)+[\s]*\{[^}]+\}([\s]*\})?
```

my sample text is:

> View hashtags #BrandPositioning#DesignThinking#DesignandInnovation #DigitalCustomerDesign#DigitalCustomerExperience#DigitalCustomerInnovation#DigitalDesign #DigitalDesignandInnovation #DigitalDesignDelivery #DigitalDesignRealization #DigitalEnterpriseExperience#DigitalServiceDesign#ExperienceDesign #Fjord #GraphicDesign #LivingServices#ServiceandExperienceDesign#ServiceDesign#UserCenteredThinking

Upon checking the error is

> expression took longer than 250ms to execute

Why is this? And how to cure?.

Comment: This would benefit from additional detail, e.g.programming language, what exactly you're attempting to achieve. At first glance it seems as though you're trying to extract some hashtags from some html? Regex may not be the best solution.

Comment: @Chris I edited the question. I'm using C#, the regex is to extract CSS from string

Comment: Do you realize that your sample text has not even one css property ?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub Yup I did that on purpose. I tested on strings that have css properties in the string, and on strings that don't have css properties in it. :-)

Comment: You should show us your C# code

Comment: how about trying the pattern here: http://regexr.com/
and there you'll see the timeout error?

Answer (score 1):

What you experience is called catastrophic backtracking and it occurs because your pattern have redundant parts.

You have two options:

- make leading tests to avoid run regex against useless input
- simplify your regex

What seems to cause the backtracking is `((\.|\#|\[)[^\s,\.\#\|]+)*` that you can transform to `((\.|\#|\[)[^\s,\.\#\|]*)`

Comment: Do you have an alternative regex pattern for catching CSS selectors and properties?

Comment: This matches only the first instance of #id and .class, and not the next #id and .class that follow

Comment: @tjvg1991 could you provide your input so I could test the regex better?